# About an inequality in Royden's Real Analysis

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

I want to show for $p\geq1$

$|\text{sgn}(a)|a|^{1/p}-\text{sgn}(b)|b|^{1/p}|^{p}\leq 2^{p}|a-b|$.

But I am not getting minus sign on right hand side. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: How is $a^{1/p}$ defined when $a<0$.

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: Why can't you take the p-th root of both sides? Then consider a>0 and b<0.

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes. I have corrected it. This is problem no.46 in Chapter 7 from Royden's  Real Analysis (4th edition)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do.

Let $a>0,b>0$. Let $a^{1/p}-b^{1/p}>0$. Thus $a=(a^{1/p}-b^{1/p}+b^{1/p})^p\geq (a^{1/p}-b^{1/p})^p+b\implies (a^{1/p}-b^{1/p})^p\leq a-b\leq 2^p|a-b|$. Similarly, if $b^{1/p}-a^{1/p}>0$, then we can show that $(b^{1/p}-a^{1/p})^p\leq 2^p|a-b|$. Thus $|\text{sgn}(a)|a|^{1/p}-\text{sgn}(b)|b|^{1/p}|^p\leq 2^p|a-b|$.

Let $a>0,b<0$. Thus $|\text{sgn}(a)|a|^{1/p}-\text{sgn}(b)|b|^{1/p}|^p=(|a|^{1/p}+|b|^{1/p})^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|a|+|b|)\leq 2^p|a-b|$ as $x\mapsto x^p$ is convex.

Let $a<0,b>0$. Then $\text{sgn}(a)|a|^{1/p}-\text{sgn}(b)|b|^{1/p}=|b|^{1/p}-|a|^{1/q}$. Thus as we have done in the first case we can show that $|\text{sgn}(a)|a|^{1/p}-\text{sgn}(b)|b|^{1/p}|^p\leq 2^p|a-b|$.

The case $a<0,b<0$ will be similar to second case.